# Simplifying python module tree

Tags: python, structure, python-module

I tried to find an answer to this question but unsuccessfully.

**How can I keep a simple module tree (module, submodule, etc.) when splitting the code in multiple files?**

More precisely, if I put directly my main class `Load` in `__init__.py`, it can be conveniently accessed with `mymodule.Load`, and instantiated with `mymodule.Load()`. I can also have children classes, such as `LoadTXT`, also in `__init__.py`, which are easily instantiated with `mymodule.LoadTXT()`.

Now, if these classes are large and I wish to split them in multiple files, I have the following option:

```
mymodule/
    __init__.py # empty
    Load.py     # contains class Load
    LoadTXT.py  # contains class LoadTXT and imports class Load
```

but this means I must use `mymodule.LoadTXT.LoadTXT()` to instantiate `LoadTXT`, which is cumbersome and ugly.

I have thought about using `execfile` or `exec` instead, but this does not sound very pythonic, and it looks ugly.

Note that I gave a fairly simple example, but in my actual situation, I would need several folders (submodules), each having the same problem. The tree then really becomes a mess.

Comment: Just `from LoadTXT import LoadTXT` in your `__init__.py`. Then it's accessible from the module. Read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Naming modules in PascalCase is probably a bad idea, especially if it causes them to share a name with their class

Comment: @jonrsharpe, This is a good way to go, thanks. However, it does not really change the structure of the tree. It simply makes a shortcut. The `__repr__` of `LoadTXT` will still return `mymodule.LoadTXT.LoadTXT`.

Comment: And why does that matter? Write a better representation if you want to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I guess users can get lost when inspecting the module structure. I am always a bit reluctant to import names like that. But maybe that is the right solution ...

Comment: But you don't have to *"import names like that"*, that's exactly the point I'm making. It makes it *simpler* for the users, they just do `from mymodule import LoadTXT`.